# Why ANSI escape sequence included in an error message for parsing issues; Parsing issues when using read_tsv even with n_max = 1

Tags: r, parsing, readr

I have some code to import 16 txt files containing data. It will import that data and generate a list containing it but also output `There were 16 warnings (use warnings() to see them)` so it looks like every single file is giving a warning. These are txt files up to 0.5 GB in size and may import with up to ~500,000 rows of data each prior to going through the filter().

I'm on a Mac mini with an M1 chip, using RStudio Version 2023.03.1+446, and version 4.3.0.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create paths vector
paths <- list.files("origdata", pattern = "[.]txt$", full.names = TRUE)

# Create import function
importclean <- function(x) {
  x |> 
  read_tsv(
    id = "pathname", 
    na = c("NULL"),
    name_repair = toupper # convert 
  ) |> 
  mutate( # Parse out year from file name and convert to 20## format
    YEAR = parse_number(pathname) + 2000,
    .keep = "unused",
    .before = 1
  ) |>
  filter(
    if_any(
      contains("idcode"), ~ . %in%
        c(
          00100:00200,
          00500:00600,
          01000:02000
        )
    )
  )
}

datalist <- paths |>
  set_names(basename) |>
  map(importclean)
```

If I use `warnings(datalist)` or `warnings(datalist[[...]])` for each of the 16 elements in the output list, the warning is identical. If I use `problems(datalist[[...]])` for every one of the 16 elements, no output is generated.

```
Warning messages:
1: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details, e.g.:
  dat <- vroom(...)
  problems(dat) Error in cat("1: \033[38;5;254mOne or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details, e.g.:\n  dat <- vroom(...)\n  problems(dat)\033[39m",  : 
  argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

I'm expecting to get an output list that contains 16 elements with each element being a data frame. My intent is to eventually use list_rbind to combine them.

If I set the n_max argument for read_tsv to 1 so I import only the first row of data from each txt file (this row may or may not be filtered out by `filter()`), I only end up with 3 warning messages about parsing issues. Running warning() with n_max = 1 still gives the above error, ANSI escape codes, and all that.

I've also tried commenting out both the mutate() and filter() blocks of code while setting n_max = 1 so I don't think they are the issue,

Why are ANSI escape codes showing up in my error messages? And what's wrong with my code that is causing the parsing issue?

Comment: It sounds like those values are in the txt files them selves. Do you know how they were created? If they were created in R with something like `capture.output` then those code are inserted when R tries for format them in a "pretty" style for the terminal.

Comment: I do not know how they were created and the user guide for the data files unfortunately does not explain either. Is there a way to go directly into the txt file to clean it up first? I’ve tried opening them in TextEdit but it freezes up.

Comment: If you are on a mac, maybe you can use `grep` in the terminal to see if "parsing issues" appears in the file or not. If it does, you can grab a few lines around that match to extract a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm running "grep 033 PATHTOMYFILE" and can't find that escape sequence in the files. No parsing errors either.

Comment: When I run select() to pick out on the rows I need, prior to running list_rbind(), I do not get any errors. But I am getting various errors when I include all columns. So I'm suspecting some of the columns do in fact contain some junk that is inserted into the data as you've suggested.